# Why do I recieve a runtime error on codeforces?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the task: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/492/B
And here is my code:

```
n, l = map(int, input().split())
 
lantern = []
 
for i in range(n):
    a = int(input())
    lantern.append(a)
 
lantern.sort()
 
print(lantern)
 
if (lantern[0] >= (l-lantern[n-1])):
    r = lantern[0]
else:
    r = l-lantern[n-1]
 
for i in range(n-2):
    if (lantern[i+1] - lantern[i])/2 > r:
        r = (lantern[i+1] - lantern[i])/2
 
print(r)
```

So, what should I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `n` integers are on a single line, and your code handles `n` line separated inputs. Change it to

```py
n, l = map(int, input().split())
 
lantern = list(map(int, input().split()))
lantern.sort()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, everything works fine!

Comment: @LevGor considering upvoting if it solves your purpose

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't upvote as I have less then 15 reputation